# How to extract a limited number of messages from history, ejabberd + strophe.js

Tags: javascript, ejabberd, strophe.js

I am using ejabberd and strophe.js, I can store the messages and extract them by timestamp(strophe.mam.js plugin), but how to extract them by limit, last 5 or 10 messages?